# Why is Cohen's Kappa bounded by $-1$ and $1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Cohen's Kappa test statistic is designed to be bounded by $-1$ and $1$. But I don't quite undersatnd how that is guaranteed. The statistic is defined as

$$\kappa = \frac{p_o - p_e}{1 - p_e}$$

where $p_o$ is the observed accuracy (number of agreed upon items between two classifiers divided by number of all items) and $p_e$ is the expected accuracy (average expected accuracy per category, where the expected accuracy per category is the product of the relative frequency of category $c$ from the distribution of the first classifier and the frequency of $c$ in the distribution of the second classifier).

Or expressed in code, as I find that more easily understood:

```
def compute_expected_accuracy(distr1, distr2):

    num_classes = len(np.unique(np.concatenate([distr1, distr2])))

    counts_distr1 = np.bincount(distr1, minlength=num_classes)
    counts_distr2 = np.bincount(distr2, minlength=num_classes)

    items_total_distr1 = np.sum(counts_distr1)
    items_total_distr2 = np.sum(counts_distr2)

    expected_acc_per_class = counts_distr1/items_total_distr1
    expected_correct_per_class = counts_distr2*expected_acc_per_class

    return np.sum(expected_correct_per_class)/items_total_distr2


def compute_observed_accuracy(distr1, distr2):

    return np.sum(distr1==distr2)/len(distr1)


def cohens_kappa(distr1, distr2):

    exp_acc = compute_expected_accuracy(distr1, distr2)
    obs_acc = compute_observed_accuracy(distr1, distr2)

    return (obs_acc - exp_acc)/(1 - exp_acc)
```

So, I understand the formula in and of itself, but I don't understand where the boundedness comes from. There is also some dependence between $p_o$ and $p_e$ which makes not all combinations possible. This dependence probably is important for why the expression is bounded. Can you point out to me though how exactly the boundedness emerges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, $\kappa\ge0$. If $\kappa>1$, then $p_o-p_e>1-p_e$ so $p_o>1$ which is a contradiction as $p_o$ is a probability.

Comment: I see, and the same holds true for $|\kappa|$, right? As $|\kappa| > 0 \implies \left| \frac{p_o - p_e}{1 - p_e}\right| > 1 \implies p_o > 1$.

Comment: @user3578468 For your argument to work, $p_o - p_e$ must be nonnegative. But in general it may be negative; in fact this is exactly the case we're considering, if we want to show $\kappa \geq -1$. I've never seen a complete proof of the lower bound; even in Cohen's original paper, the "proof" that $\kappa \geq -1$ does not address one case.